# $C^\infty$ bump function to smoothen a corner

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\beta(t)$ be a smoothener at $t=0,$ e.g. $\beta(t)=e^{-1/t},$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}^+.$  Let's say that this is a horizontal smoothener, as it flattens at $\beta(0^+)$.
Now I want another function $\varphi(t)$ which is a horizontal smoothener at $t=0^+$, but also a vertical smoothener at $t=1^-.$
Reflecting through $y=1-t$ would do the job, but I can't figure out the specific details.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with something parametric. The curve $t \mapsto (e^{-1/(1-t)}, e^{-1/t})$ is everywhere infinitely differentiable on $(0,1)$. As $t \to 0$, its $y$-derivatives all vanish while its $x$-derivative remains nonzero, while the opposite happens as $t \to 1$. (It connects the points $(0,1/e)$ and $(1/e,0)$, while you seem to want a curve connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, but that's not hard to patch up...)

If you need to express this as the graph of a function, you can then solve for $y$ in terms of $x$: $x=e^{-1/(1-t)}$, so $t = 1 + \frac{1}{\ln x}$, and $y=\exp\left(\frac{-1}{1+\frac{1}{\ln x}}\right)=x^{-1/(1+\ln x)}$.

Comment: That's the way to go!   
While I had tried polar functions, I was missing these parametrics staring right at me.  Thanks.

Comment: For the curious minded, the reference problem from which this appeared states the following:  Show that the closure of a submanifold may be a bad set, such as a fractal. More precisely, for any closed subset $C \subset \mathbf{T}^{2},$  construct an injective $C^{\infty}$
  function $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{T}^{3}$ for which $\overline{f(\mathbf{R})} \cap (\mathbf{T}^2 \times \{0\}) = C \times \{0\}.$  Here's a link to the reference [Dave Morris Witte.](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/Ratner.html)